# “Cannot send empty message” When trying to send emojis my bot has access to

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get all emojis that my bot had access to from all servers it is in. The bot is in like 35 server so I will get a bit of emojis. Whenever I run the command in console I get `DISCORD API ERROR: Cannot send empty message`

My code:

```js
const emojiList = msg.guild.emojis.cache.map(emoji => emoji.toString()).join(" ");
  msg.channel.send(`${emojiList}`)
```

Comment: If you `console.log()` your `emojiList`, is there anything in it or is it just empty?

Comment: When I console.log it just logs nothing. Another line is added but it’s blank.

Comment: And that is one part of your problem. `emojiList` is just an empty `array` and the `send()` function doesn't want empty strings/arrays :D

Comment: So what do I do to fix it?

Comment: Maybe instead of using `emoji.toString()`, you can use `emoji.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter how many servers the bot is in, it only sends the emotes of the server in which the command is used, firstly make sure the server has emotes of its own. secondly try logging `emojiList`

This you can either use an escape character or (\n) on this

```
const emotes = message.guild.emojis.cache.map(emoji => emoji.toString()).join(' ');
   message.channel.send(emojiList);;
console.log(emotes);
msg.channel.send(emotes);
```

Comment: Same things happens. Just adds a blank line.

Comment: hm weird it worked perfectly for me, check the code again added an edit

Comment: I can’t be doing something wrong? I copied and pasted what you had.

Comment: @Krazimike did you try sending it to the channel?

Comment: Could I contact you on discord or could you msg me? KraziDev#9249

Comment: @Krazimike here's my tag EJ BEAN#3961 send a req

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```js
const emojiList = msg.guild.emojis.cache.map(emoji => emoji.toString()).join('/n');
   msg.channel.send(`${emojiList}`);
```

Replaced empty space with `'\n'`.

Also, try `message.channel.send(emojList, { split: true });` instead of `.join`.

Comment: I literally just keep getting the “cannot send empty message” error.

Comment: @Krazimike Better than `.join`. try `message.channel.send(emojList, { split: true });`.

Comment: this wont work, the map returns emotes not ID's, check my post you need the escape character

Comment: one more thing the slash is the other way \ not /

Comment: @EJBEAN I am confused between the two. Thank you. :)

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour yeah np, also your code works it was my bad, turns out the guy was using the command in a server without any emotes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233105/discussion-between-kevin-m-mansour-and-ejbean).